# MySQL rollback on duplicate key

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, commit, rollback

I'm looking forward use transaction and rollback in case of error (like duplicate keys or else).

When I disable the autocommit and when the error came, transactions has been commited even if they shouldn't.

Here's par tof my code :

```
CREATE TABLE `Users` (
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Miscs` (
  `misc_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`misc_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SET @@AUTOCOMMIT = 0;

BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO Miscs ( misc_id ) VALUES('1');
    INSERT INTO Users ( user_id ) VALUES('1');
    INSERT INTO Miscs ( misc_id ) VALUES('2');
COMMIT;

BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO Miscs ( misc_id ) VALUES('3');
    INSERT INTO Users ( user_id ) VALUES('2');
    INSERT INTO Miscs ( misc_id ) VALUES('4');
COMMIT;

BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO Miscs ( misc_id ) VALUES('5');
    INSERT INTO Users ( user_id ) VALUES('1');
    -- should stop, rollback the transaction and skip to the next/last
    INSERT INTO Miscs ( misc_id ) VALUES('6');
COMMIT;

-- last transaction
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO Miscs ( misc_id ) VALUES('7');
    INSERT INTO Users ( user_id ) VALUES('4');
    INSERT INTO Miscs ( misc_id ) VALUES('8');
COMMIT;

SET @@AUTOCOMMIT = 1;
```

But the results is quite strange :

```
Users :
1
2
3

Miscs :
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you dropping the tables prior to running this?

Comment: Make sure the tables are actually InnoDB - if you create them as InnoDB, but InnoDB is not installed on the server, they will be created as MyISAM tables

Answer (score 1):

In the application I would write something like this -

```
START TRANSACTION
TRY
  INSERT
  INSERT
  INSERT
  COMMIT
CATCH
  ROLLBACK
```

But MySQL does not have TRY-CATCH clause. I could suggest you this way, with a [DECLARE EXIT HANDLER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-handler.html) statement -

```
  BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION  ROLLBACK;
    START TRANSACTION;
      INSERT INTO Miscs ( misc_id ) VALUES('1');
      INSERT INTO Users ( user_id ) VALUES('1');
      INSERT INTO Miscs ( misc_id ) VALUES('2');
    COMMIT;
  END;

  BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION  ROLLBACK;
    START TRANSACTION;
      INSERT INTO Miscs ( misc_id ) VALUES('3');
      INSERT INTO Users ( user_id ) VALUES('2');
      INSERT INTO Miscs ( misc_id ) VALUES('4');
    COMMIT;
  END;

  BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION  ROLLBACK;
    START TRANSACTION;
      INSERT INTO Miscs ( misc_id ) VALUES('5');
      INSERT INTO Users ( user_id ) VALUES('1');
      -- should stop, rollback the transaction and skip to the next/last
      INSERT INTO Miscs ( misc_id ) VALUES('6');
    COMMIT;
  END;

  BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION  ROLLBACK;
    START TRANSACTION;
      INSERT INTO Miscs ( misc_id ) VALUES('7');
      INSERT INTO Users ( user_id ) VALUES('4');
      INSERT INTO Miscs ( misc_id ) VALUES('8');
    COMMIT;
  END;
```

Run this code from the stored procedure, because in MySQL it is not possible to use DECLARE handlers in the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

See [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-error-handling.html)

> A duplicate-key error rolls back the SQL statement, if you have not specified the IGNORE option in your statement.